# Merge mysql recordset in vba

Tags: mysql, sql, vba

I want to use combobox selected value as query to pull another data from mysql database. Let's say Combobox selected value as id. then I will use this id to pull another details related to this id such as supplier, cost etc. to display in label option. I used following code but it doesn't work.

sqlQa = "select Description from matcat_select where BOF like 'MAIN';"

rs.Open sqlQa, oConn, adOpenStatic

With rs

```
    'Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing 'Disconnect the recordset.
        k = .Fields.Count
     'Populate the array with the whole recordset.
    vaData = .GetRows
End With
```

'Manipulate the Combobox's properties and show the form.

```
With UserForm1
    With .ComboBox1
        .Clear
        .BoundColumn = k
        .List = Application.Transpose(vaData)
        .ListIndex = -1
    End With
End With
```

'Manipulate the Combobox's properties and show the form

Set rs1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

sqlQb = "Select EOF From matcat_select Where Description = '" & ComboBox1.Value & "';"

rs1.Open sqlQb, oConn

While Not rs1.EOF

Label6.Caption = rs1("EOF")

rs1.MoveNext

Wend

Please check my code and correct me if I am wrong. Also, each time I made query in mysql via vba am I need to establish a connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Not rs1.EOF Then

Label6.Caption = rs1("EOF")

Else

Label6.Caption = ""

End If
```

Try this

```
While Not rs1.EOF
 Label6.Caption = rs1("EOF")
 rs1.MoveNext
Wend
```

For the select statement

```
sqlQb = "Select EOF From MyTable Where Description = '" & ComboBox1.Value & "';"
```

ComboBox is not a text box. To get the selected value, use .Value method.

Yes you need a connection when you want to execute any queries, your VBA is not a database itself, it doesn't knows what you want.

recordset.Open Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Tried to paste it. It shows error and highlight While Not rs1.EOF Then  as red color. Pls help me to figure it out. Tnks.

Comment: Once i pasted, it turns red and shows compile error. Expected - end of statement. Tnks

Comment: Opps sorry. I copy-paste your code and forgot to remove the "Then" keyword for While loop.

Comment: Solved error issue. But, still label doesn't show up the combobox selection. Could u pls check below select query sqlQb = "Select EOF From MyTable Where Description = " & ComboBox1.Text Am i need to declare the combobox value as string or something else ? How to link string value between mysql and vba ?

Comment: Sorry. I can't figure out difference in code. Pls highlight. Tnks.

Comment: Look at the bolded part.

Comment: Got it. It shows syntax error as "you have an error in your syntax; Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near" at line 1. Pls advise me. Tnks.

Comment: I believe error in select query but debug options shows rs1.Open sqlQb, conn as highlighted yellow.

Comment: I have edited to add in the concatenation for the query.

Comment: It works without error. However, label doesn't showup EOF value. FYI, each item contains two fields such as description and EOF. I want to see the EOF value based on description selected in combobox. Now, i believe it records data from db but why doesn't show up in label ?

Comment: It could be that your select query returns no row / null row. Need more info on the selected data that is in Combo Box and your SQL 'MyTable' table before I could help you with your WHERE query.

Comment: select Description FROM MyTable; what does that returns? And what's your Combo Box value?

Comment: Let's say description column have standard item and Mechanical.. whereas EOF has it's notation such as STR and M respectively. Combobox option are description column list. if user select Mechanical then label should show it's notation STR. make sense ?

Comment: Presently, label doesn't show up anything upon user selection in combobox.

Comment: I pasted complete code for combobox and label query. Pls check it and advise me. Tnks for your time.